# Configuration issue in Data Source via Spring Java Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using following way to create sessionFactory.

```
    @Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    //sessionFactory.setConfigLocation(getConfigLocation());
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
    sessionFactory.setMappingResources(getMappingResources());
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean(destroyMethod="close")
public DataSource restDataSource() {

    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.password"));
    dataSource.setInitialSize(env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dbcp.initialSize", Integer.class));
    dataSource.setMaxActive(env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dbcp.maxActive", Integer.class));
    dataSource.setMaxIdle(env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle", Integer.class));
    dataSource.setMinIdle(env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dbcp.minIdle", Integer.class));
    return dataSource;
}
```

I want to use JNDI Name configured on Tomcat Server for instantiating the Data Source.

So I created another Bean

```
@Bean    
public DataSource dataSource() {
            //Method 1
            JndiObjectFactoryBean dataSource= new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
            dataSource.setJndiName("java:comp/env/jdbc/test");
            dataSource.setResourceRef(true);
            try {
                dataSource.afterPropertiesSet();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | NamingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return (DataSource)dataSource.getObject();

            //Method 2
            /*final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
            dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
            DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("java:comp/env/jdbc/test");
            return dataSource;*/

            }
```

When I use sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource()); ,I am not able to instantiate the DataSource and get following Exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1825)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1783)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1868)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:242)
....
...


Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL ''
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Regards,
Ankur

Comment: The problem is that you are using a properties file containing hibernate configuration properties. I suspect the file is named `hibernate.properties`. Rename it to something else. Also it is a factory bean and that should be managed by the container, you shouldn't call `afterPropertiesSet` or `getObject` . Call that from the config of the `LocalSessionFactoryBean`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you try to use 'hibernate.connection.driver_class' property which is not set.

Comment: No,If you read the question instantiation happens successfully when i use restDataSource() Bean. but fails when I use dataSource() bean while instantiating sessionFactory. in dataSource() bean I am not using "hibernate.connection.driver_class" anywhere. Driver class is specified in the JNDI that is setup on Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
    sessionFactory.setMappingResources(getMappingResources());
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties()); // Problematic line
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

The main problem is that you are using placeholders that have the same name as [hibernate properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-optional) and injecting all the properties in the `LocalSessionFactoryBean`. I strongly recommend against it, also if your file is named `hibernate.properties` and is in the root of the classpath it will be automatically picked up by hibernate. I suggest just injecting the properties you need and not everything.

I would also suggest rewriting your `sessionFactory()` method give it a `DataSource` parameter, this will automatically be injected with the available `DataSource`.

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    sessionFactory.setMappingResources(getMappingResources());
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties()); // Problematic line
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Instead of using the `JndiObjectFactoryBean` I suggest the `JndiDataSourceLookup` or a direct usage of the `JndiLocatorDelegate`. That saves you the hassel of the `JndiObjectFactoryBean` and for which your method is flawed as you are catching exceptions (which might lead to a unavailable `DataSource` which will in turn trigger hibernate to do the configuration himself. (Which is what appears to be happening now).

I would also suggest the use of profiles that way you could have a manually configured datasource for testing/local deployment and a jndi based one for production usage.